# Why does the (n²) change based on brackets?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have two basic excercises:

a.) 4-7² (3+2x6-10²)-10x2+8

b.) (4-7²) 3 + (2x6-10)²-10(2+8)

In excercise a. 4-7² gives me: **4+49**

In excercise b. (4-7²) gives me: **4-49**

Why does in excercise b. -7² not equal (-7 x -7) ?

Comment: The issue is that in one case you interpreted it as $-(7^2)$ and in the other case as $(-7)^2$.

Comment: See [Order of operations](https://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html) : the usual convention is that exponents (powers, roots) must be performed before multiply, divide, add or subtract. Thus, if there are no parentheses, $4-7^2=4-49$

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the math stack exchange.

The way you've written it the values should not be any different from exercise a and b. If however, in exercise a, it is written as $4 + (-7)^2$ then it would give you the value of $4 + 49$. Usually, when we have $-a^2$ this is equivalent to the negative of $a^2$ and not $-a*-a$. Hope this helps. In future, you may also wish to use MathJax as people seem to heavily prefer it here.